# MDI window title in Windows 10

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, windows-10

I'm testing Delphi applications on Windows 10 and I was intrigued a difference in rendering the window frames on MDI forms.

It is the intention?

[image: MDI title difference]

Comment: Out of interest, the same behaviour happens with an application written in VS 2015 so it isn't a Delphi issue (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/950f3293-b329-492a-a1b8-d11b12f96c18/cant-change-mdi-child-title-bar-color-in-windows-10?forum=winforms)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I presume you are talking about the minimise, maximise and close buttons at the right hand end of the caption bar.

These buttons are rendered by the system rather than Delphi and the behaviour is as designed. Microsoft deprecated MDI at least 15 years ago and so it's not at all surprising that they have not modified it to match the new style of Windows 10.

So yes, what you are observing is to be expected, and is how Microsoft intend the non-client area of MDI children to be rendered.

Comment: Is there any better concept for heavy apps with many forms? Forms docked in workplace is good idea.

Comment: MDI is deprecated. The VCL has a docking framework for standard forms. The ide is based around it.

Comment: Docking or tabbed interfaces are the norm now.

Comment: Docking or tabbed interfaces are useless for technical software with interactive windows. One reason why WIndows>>>>>>>>>>Mac.