# Can't change MDI child title bar color in Windows 10

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, winapi

If I create a simple WinForms app in Windows 10 and an MDI child window within:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IsMdiContainer = true;
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
    f2.MdiParent = this;           
    f2.Show();
}
```

I can change the color of the main app window through the "Personalization" settings in Windows 10 (to red, in this screen shot).  However, there seems to be no way to change the color of the title bar in the MDI child, either in code or Windows 10 settings. (Windows 7 allowed this to be changed, but Win 10 seems to have removed that ability).

Question: Is there a way to change the color of the MDI child title bar either in code or Windows 10 settings? (I think it should probably match the color of the MDI container)

[image: WinForm]

Comment: Good to know WinForms are still alive :)

Comment: @nikhilvartak - just barely :)

Comment: tagging this as win32 bc likely the mdi components are that way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31959800/mdi-window-title-in-windows-10